# How to properly use @Alternative for client implementations

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1, qualifiers

EDIT: I changed the CDI injections points from using @EJB to using @Inject as indicated in my below comments. Just an FYI.

---

I have two EAR projects, both basically the same.  The only difference they have are a few client specific implementations, where required.  I'm having a problem, however.

This is what I have:

EAR #1 contains the following modules:

```
web.war 
ejb-default.jar
ejb-client-1.jar
```

EAR #2 contains the following modules:

```
web.war
ejb-default.jar
ejb-client-2.jar
```

In ejb-default contains the following:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ApplicationSettingsBean implements ApplicationSettingsBeanLocal
```

Now, for EAR #1, the ejb-client-1.jar might be empty, so any EJB injections should use whatever is in ejb-default.

For EAR #2, however, I want to override the default implementation with a client specific one.  For example:

```
@Singleton
@Startup    
@Alternative
public class ApplicationSettingsBean implements ApplicationSettingsBeanLocal {
```

I also created the following beans.xml entry in ejb-client-2:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <alternatives>
        <class>com.client2.ejb.ApplicationSettingsBean</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

I would expect that the @Alternative implementation would be injected when such an implementation exists.  If @Default is specified at the injection point, then the default implementation (ejb-default) should be injected.  Though, that doesn't happen:

```
    // Inject the alternative implementation
    @Inject
    private ApplicationSettingsBeanLocal appSettingsBean;
```

With this CDI, the default is being injected, not the alternative.  That's not the expected behavior.

Comment: So, I changed all my injection points from using `@EJB` to `@Inject`, as recommended by Gavin King on another forum, and that eliminated the error.  It did not solve the problem, though.  Now, the @Alternative implementation is ignored in favor of the `@Default` (implied annotation) implementation.  I double checked my beans.xml in the second EJB jar, and it looks good.

Comment: http://www.seamframework.org/107780.lace

Comment: Above code has been changed to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **beans.xml** where you have to specify the Alternatives, 
have to be inside the *ejb-default.jar* not in the *ejb-client-2.jar*.

The CDI specification (1.1, but applicable as well to the previous implementation) states at chapter 5.1 that:

> An alternative is not available for injection, lookup or EL resolution
>   to classes or JSP/JSF pages in a module unless the module is a bean
>   archive and the alternative is explicitly selected in that bean
>   archive.

In other words, you must select the alternative in the same module of the class which uses the bean.

Comment: Had the same issue, a WAR module referencing a simple JAR that holds some stateless beans. Interface of one of them gets injected in a REST resource in the WAR via CDI. Didn't work although IT tests in JAR were fine and cost me 3h of research till I found your post. Thankz man, now I can go for Christmas ;)

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering what's going on, this mixes CDI and EJB (EE5) injection. That's why the first error occurs. Alternatives are a CDI idea and @EJB doesn't recognize them.

The reason for the default instead of the alternative is because that is the qualifier being used on the injection (alternatives don't have @Default implied). This essentially tells CDI I know exactly which instance I want, it's the one with the same qualifiers I'm using at the injection. The best way handle things like this is to simply use @Inject without any qualifiers unless you know EXACTLY which instance you want and you add those qualifiers to the injection (the same ones on the implementing class).

Comment: Yeah, right on.  It took me a minute to figure out that `@Alternative` was only for `@Inject` injection points, and not available for `@EJB`.  After making the need changes, however, the `@Alternative` class is still not recognized over the default implementation.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Which app server are you using? Also where are your beans.xml files, especially the one with the alternative? Where is that being invoked, the war?

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.  I have an empty `beans.xml` in `ejb-default.jar`, which contains the default implementation.  I have a `beans.xml` (with the appropriate alternate markup) in the `ejb-client-2.jar`, which contains the `@Alternative` implementation.  I'm injecting the EJB (using `@Inject`) from a managed bean in the WAR.

Comment: I think that is the issue, calling from the war. The war doesn't know anything about the alternative. Just for kicks and giggles, add the alternative to the war and see what happens. If you're not on 3.1.2.2 you could also try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I'll try that and report back.